# Efficient way to average xarray datasets over a set of pixels

Tags: python, indexing, python-xarray

I have two types of xarray datasets.

- One containing information on the classification of land, which returns an integer for each class.
- Temperature datasets for different data source with different resolutions.

I want to compute the temperature mean for all datasources for each class.

Because the different sources have different latitude and longitude resolution I first store them in an array, and have a loop over the N pixels verifying the condition (using .sel(lon=xx[i], lat=yy[i], method='nearest').
Then I compute the mean for all pixels.
What would be a more efficient way to do this?